# How to setup virtualhost for domain on CentOs 6.2 using apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, centos6

First time LAMP and domain setup on CentOs. Previous experience of this is in Ubuntu.
Working on a dedicated server package of my local ISP. They installed default CentOs 6.2 and redirected my domain to the server. Pinging mydomain.com works fine to reach the server's IP.

I have successfully installed LAMP on the box using this [howto explanation](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.2-lamp). All seems fine.

I have edited /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1      mydomain.com
```

I have also edited the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and added the following at the end of the file, while keeping the rest default:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin myemailaddress@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com
        <Directory "/var/www/html/mydomain.com">
                Options Includes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/mydopmain.com.default.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And i also ran

```
chmod -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

as a final attempt to get things going.

Both /var/www/html and /var/www/html/mydomain.com contain a basic index.php so that i can test that everything works.

The problem i get is when i try access the domain via the browser i get an "The connection has timed out: The server at mydomain.com is taking too long to respond."

Ubuntu used the sites-available and sites-enabled, so i am not sure if i am missing a setup somewhere or if something is missing from the ISP side?

Does anyone know how to setup virtualHosts on CentOs 6.2 for apache2?

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that Apache is actually running:

```
ps -FC httpd
```

And listening on port 80:

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep httpd
```

And that you've allowed connections to port 80:

```
sudo system-config-firewall-tui
```

Comment: Many Thanks! After installing and using 'system-config-firewall-tui' I found that only SSH access was allowed but not HTTP. Enabling HTTP lead to my main index.php loading with success. So on to the next thing to get running! :P

Answer (score 0):

I believe CentOS has a firewall enabled by default.  'sudo /sbin/service iptables off' to completely disable it (this has security implications!).

When using name-based virtual hosting, if there is a name mismatch, the first defined virtual host will be used.